# Activemq stops working - activemq/zookeeper setup

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-zookeeper

I've configured 3 zookeepers and 3 activemq instances in 1 cluster.

**Scenario**

- 3 activemq instances with only 1 master and other two is slave.
- all 3 activemq instances are running, i.e. `sudo service activemq status` returns `running` but checking the logs, 1 instance(activemq1) is currently waiting for other cluster members, 1 instance(activemq2) stops, 1 instance(activemq3) has error. Assumming that we only require two instance to elect master, this setup should be able to run successfully .
- two activemq instances should be running
- zookeeper instances are running fine.

**Issue**

Below are the stacktraces of the respective activemq instances. Based on my understanding, it needs at least two properly running activemq intances for the cluster to nominate a master instance. Given that all activemq instanes produces `running` when issued with `sudo service activemq status` , I'm assuming there is an issue inside each activemq instances - refer to below stacktraces. Now, I noticed on logs, that activemq1 only fails to be properly running since other activemq instances failed internally. Notice the stacktrace on activemq2, it's stucked after it successfully connected to zookeeper and activemq3 has issue, I still need to figure out. The issue is fixed when I restarted activemq2 and activemq3. However, I can't be sure this won't happen again, thus this question.

- activem1 show the below stacktrace, which I assume that this is because the other 2 activemq instances are running but has errors

`Session establishment complete on server 10.5.4.111/10.5.4.111:2181, sessionid = 0x1582db00708000c, negotiated timeout = 4000
Not enough cluster members connected to elect a master.
Not enough cluster members connected to elect a master.
Not enough cluster members connected to elect a master.`

- activemq2 has the below stacktrace, which is the one I don't understand. It has stopped after successful connection to zookeeper, which should be detected by other activemq instances belonging to cluster-activem1 and activemq3

`Opening socket connection to server 10.5.4.111/10.5.4.111:2181
Socket connection established to 10.5.4.111/10.5.4.111:2181, initiating session
Session establishment complete on server 10.5.4.111/10.5.4.111:2181, sessionid = 0x1582db00708000d, negotiated timeout = 4000`

- activemq3 has the below stacktrace

  `org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)[apache-jsp-8.0.9.M3.jar:2.3]`

**Configuration for activemq**

the previous config here is with 2s zkSessionTimeout - which is the default. I made it to 4s as per googled to maximize the time needed for an activemq instance registers itself to zookeeper.

```
<persistenceAdapter>
        <replicatedLevelDB 
            directory="${activemq.data}/leveldb"
            replicas="3"
            bind="tcp://0.0.0.0:61619"
            zkAddress="zookeeper_addresses_here"
            hostname="activemq_hostname_here"
            zkSessionTimeout="4s"
        />
    </persistenceAdapter>
```

**Configuration for zookeeper**

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=/my/data/dir

clientPort=2181
server.1=activemq1_privateIP:2888:3888
server.2=activemq2_privateIP:2888:3888
server.3=activemq3_privateIP::2888:3888

autopurge.purgeInterval=24
autopurge.snapRetainCount=5
```

**Zookeeper version 3.4.9**

**ActiveMQ version 5.13.4**

**Setup via Opswork**

Comment: Heads up--- If this is a brand new setup, you might want to consider that Replicated LevelDB is going to be deprecated in upcoming ActiveMQ releases. If so, what is your platform requirement?  There are other high availability / replication setups that can meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. However, based on their [site](http://activemq.apache.org/masterslave.html) we'll be sticking for replicatedDB for now given that we will be using activeMQ. I have seen threads regarding the brittleness this kind of setup but have managed to become stable enough for their requirements - one of this was to increase the zkSessionTimeout for activemq to have enough time connecting to zookeeper. But it doesn't work for me i guess.

Comment: Right, I'm not suggesting to not use ActiveMQ, I'm suggesting you use an alternative master+slave configuration.  NFSv4 (shared) or GFSv2 (replicated) are much simpler to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute "directory" master-slave mq is need to refer to the same folder